# find the intersection between two sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

$A=\{x: x\in {Z} , x$ is sum of 7 consecutive integers $\}$

$B=\{x: x\in {Z} , x$ is sum of 8 consecutive integers

$C=\{x: x\in {Z} , x$ is sum of 9 consecutive integers $\}$

find $A \cap B \cap C.$

I got this problem from "Challenges and thrills on pre-college mathematics"

my first attempt was

$A=\{x\in {Z}:x=7n+28,\forall n \in {N} \}$

$B=\{x\in {Z}:x=8n+36,\forall n \in {N} \}$

$C=\{x\in {Z}:x=9n+55,\forall n \in {N} \}$

LCM of $7,8,9$ is $504$.

therefore $A \cap B \cap C = \{504x:\forall x\in {Z} \}$

is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in the description of the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$. For $x\in A$ you can prove that there exists a $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $x=7n+28$. Then you have to write
$$
A=\{x\in\mathbb Z~:~\exists n\in\mathbb Z\text{ such that }x=7n+28\}.
$$
The restriction $n\in\mathbb N$ is wrong and $\forall$ is wrong too.
But you can do it better. Because of $28=4\cdot 7$ you can say
$$
A=\{x\in\mathbb Z~:~\exists n\in\mathbb Z\text{ such that }x=7n\}.
$$
Further, you get
$$
B=\{x\in\mathbb Z~:~\exists n\in\mathbb Z\text{ such that }x=8n+4\}
$$
$$
C=\{x\in\mathbb Z~:~\exists n\in\mathbb Z\text{ such that }x=9n\}.
$$
From $x\in A\cap B\cap C$ you can conclude that there exists $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $x=7\cdot(8n+4)\cdot 9=504n+252$. Hence, 
$$
A\cap B\cap C\subset\{x\in\mathbb Z~:~\exists n\in\mathbb Z\text{ such that }x=504n+252\}=:D.
$$

Now, consider $x\in D$ and you have to argue why $x\in A\cap B\cap C$ holds, which is easy to see.

Comment: I hope that I fixed it now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an error (In the first answer)

$$C=\{x\in\mathbb Z~:~\exists n\in\mathbb Z\text{ such that }x=9n{\color{Red} +1}\}$$